# Comparing to a hardcoded string with quotes in C++

Tags: c++, googletest, tinyxml

I'm writing a c++ function to generate XML using TinyXML. I'd like to verify that a (relatively small) tree produced by my function gets turned into a string identical to a reference string.

```
// intended XML:
<element type="correct" />
```

It seems like the easiest way to do this comparison is to hardcode the reference string into the code:

```
//assignment
std::string intended = "<element type=\"correct\" />";
```

However, the backslashes to escape the quotes prevent the comparison from succeeding.

```
#include <tinyxml.h>
#include <string.h>
TiXmlElement test = TiXmlElement("element");
test.SetAttribute("type", "correct");
TiXmlPrinter printer;
test.Accept(&printer);
ASSERT_EQ(intended, printer.CStr()); // gtests macro
```

output:

```
Value of: printer.CStr()
Actual: "<element type="correct" />"
Expected: intended
Which is: "<element type=\"correct\" />"
```

Comment: The backslashes wouldn't be part of the string with the code you've shown here. Something else must be going on. http://ideone.com/3H9PB7

Comment: @tasteslikelemons You could try to `printf()` (or something similar) the value from `printer.CStr()` into another variable (or stream) to see if it then gets properly formatted to match your test case.

Comment: Perhaps the strings are encoded differently. Try outputting boths strings (i.e. using std::cout) so that you can see exactly what `printer.CStr()` and `intended` look like.

Comment: Strings won't compare equal if they have different number of spaces, one contains a `'\t'` where the other has a plain `' '`, or if one ends in `'\n'` and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On the [googletest Primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/1f87a0970dc0880c954ea4066fd7b72fad6fb089/googletest/docs/Primer.md) page I read that `ASSERT_EQ()` compares pointers. (which are only equal if they point to the same memory location). If you want to compare C strings, you should use `ASSERT_STREQ()`.

```
ASSERT_STREQ(intended, printer.CStr());
```

If you want to compare `std::string` objects, you can do it this way<sup>1</sup>:

```
ASSERT_EQ(intended, printer.Str());
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Contributed by [johnfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336991/johnfo) through a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364502/comparing-to-a-hardcoded-string-with-quotes-in-c/22364916#comment110366910_22364916).

Comment: Nice spot. The oddest thing is that the diagnostic output message escapes quotes in the expected but not the actual.

Comment: Perfect. In making this change I also noticed that ASSERT_STREQ takes pointers to cost char arrays--probably to prevent exactly the kinds of representation mismatches that were confusing me.

Comment: I would mention the case insensitive assertions `ASSERT_STRCASEEQ` and `ASSERT_STRCASENE` even though this is out of the question's scope

Comment: Apart from the suggestion that the strings are not actually correct, the obvious thing to do would be to use Str() instead of CStr() so:

    ASSERT_EQ(indended, printer.Str());

this will then do an std::string comparison, so == would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: The documentation was moved to [assertions.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/assertions.md).